# Import code from a programmed microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller

I developed a project for AT89C51 microcontroller few years ago. I am still using a device with this project hardware. But the soft copy (`.asm` code) is missing from my notebook and I need to make another hardware with the same `.asm` code .

Is there any way to copy the code from a programmed 8051 microcontroller and burn it to another 8051 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible as well as not possible depending on which controller you use. These microcontrollers have something called Fuse in it which does not allow the code to be copied back from microcontroller. If you did not lock this fuse, you can use the same program that you used to import the code from micorcontroller. Or probably some burner programs.

Remember even if you are successful in getting the code from controller, it will be in HEX format which will be difficult to read and understand but you can use decompiler to change the HEX to source code.

Reference :
http://www.avrfreaks.net/forum/convert-hex-assembly-code?name=PNphpBB2&file=viewtopic&t=62400

Comment: If not fused it will be just raw binary if/when you read it.  And you have the further problem that 8051 is too generic of a backend, the code is talking to features specific to that 8051 as well as peripherals specific to that chip or design which may not match your new design.  If it is a clone of the original in all aspects and you can extrat the binary then sure you can just burn it into the clone.

Comment: @old_timer , Very helpful !! you save my time.